# How to make this superscript position lower?

Tags: superscripts

I have seen this symbol in a textbook.
[image]

I tried `\overline{\mathbb R}^+`, but the plus sign position is higher than as in the picture.
[image]

Could you elaborate on this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it was written like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
\overline{\mathbb R}{}^+
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]